# Symfony, submit html form to controller using ajax

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, symfony

Im trying to send data of a hmtl form to a controller using AJAX, but the controller doesnt receive the data as the error shows.

html form:

```
<form id="evento" name="evento" method="post" >     
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="evento-titulo" class="col-form-label">Título:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="evento_titulo" name="evento_titulo">
      </div>          
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="evento_descripcion" class="col-form-label">Descripción:</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="evento_descripcion" name="evento_descripcion"></textarea>
      </div>          
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="evento_inicio" class="col-form-label">Inicio:</label>
        <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="evento_inicio" name="evento_inicio">
      </div>          
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="evento_fin" class="col-form-label">Fin:</label>
        <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="evento_fin" name="evento_fin">
      </div>              
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="evento_checkmail" class="col-form-label">
             <input type="checkbox"  id="chkmail" name="chkmail" style="vertical-align:middle;">            
             Añadir correo  &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
             Color:
             <input type="color"  id="color" name="color" style="vertical-align:middle;">

        </label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="evento_mail" name="evento_mail" disabled="disabled">
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success" id="save_event" name="save_event">Confirmar</button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

---

Passing form data to controller through ajax:

```
$("#evento").submit(function(){     
    var data = $('#evento').serialize();        
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        url: {{ render( controller('CalendarBundle:Calendar:addEvent')) }},
        success: function(data) 
        {
            console.log($data);
            alert('OK');
        }  
    });         });
```

---

Controller:

```
public function addEventAction() {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    //fetch the POST Data

    $request = $this->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();
    $data = $request->request->all();


    $evento = new Evento();


    $evento->setBeginat(new \DateTime($data["evento_inicio"]));
    $evento->setEndat(new \DateTime($data["evento_fin"]));
    $evento->setTitle($data["evento_titulo"]);
    $evento->setMail($data["evento_mail"]);
    $evento->setDescription($data["evento_descripcion"]);
    $evento->setColor($data["color"]);

    $em->persist($evento);
    $em->flush();

    //return response
    $serializedEntity = $this->container->get('serializer')->serialize($evento, 'json');
    $response = new Response($serializedEntity);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return $response;

}}
```

This is the error message

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Notice: Undefined index: evento_inicio").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your AJAX url property is not the good one, you should just call the URL (Route) associated with the controller action addEventAction().

Let's say your route to addEventAction is "/event/add", then put `url: "/event/add"` or even if u have a name for this route then put `url: "{{ path('name_of_your_route') }}"`

The URL property of an AJAX request must be the valid address where you send the request :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your Ajax request is being sent in `application/json` content type but your controller is expecting `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Try `json_decode()`ing `$request->getContent()` to get your `$data`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this bundle to manage Symfony URL from javascript : https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle.
And keep in mind that Javascript will be executed before twig. I am sure that the error you show is displayed on page load. Good Luck